# "object.source is not a function" при использовании Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Есть массив `AutoColorArray`. Есть `input` с классом `AutoColor`.

Код:

```
var autoarr = $.unique(AutoColorArray);
console.log(autoarr);
$(".AutoColor").autocomplete({
    'source': autoarr
});
```

В итоге ошибка:

> object.source is not a function

В чем может быть дело? Сам массив состоит выглядит примерно так:

```
["Red","Black"]
```

Заполнение массива:

```
        var AutoColorArray = [];
    onChangeColors();
    getColors();
    ColorAutoComplImg();


    function onChangeColors() {
        $('[id^=Colors]').on('change', function () {
            getColors();
        });
    }


        function getColors() {
            AutoColorArray = [];
            $('[id^=Colors] option:selected').each(function () {
                AutoColorArray.push($(this).text());
            });
        }
        function ColorAutoComplImg() {
            var autoarr = $.unique(AutoColorArray);
            console.log(autoarr);
            $( ".AutoColor" ).autocomplete({
                'source': autoarr
            });

        }
```

P.S. Массив изначально является заполненным и я знаю что он не обновится в autocomplete на onchange)

Comment: [*jQuery UI Autocomplete*](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)?

Comment: Да, именно этот

Comment: @Samar проблема не воспроизводится в [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mpcmpd9y/).

Comment: @Samar какая версия *jQuery* и *jQuery UI*?

Comment: Суть в том, что это Opencart админ панель, и там autocomplete во всю работает, но он тырит данные из БД, а у меня массив заполняется данными из "select", добавил код, мб в этом дело